# how to get pending months from due entries using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the entries of monthly dues like,

Table name : month_dues,

Columns:

```
customer_id, 
due_date, 
due_amount
```

These table have lot of due entries.

```
customer_id    due_date   due_amount
--------------------------------------
1             2018-12-01   100
1             2019-01-01   100
1             2019-02-01   100
1             2019-10-01   100
```

so, how to select pending due months from these record?

in my table customer 1 not paid dues for these months,
2019-03,2019-04,2019-05,2019-06,2019-07,2019-08, 2019-09

customer pay the due every month so

For select paid dues from table using,

```
 SELECT customer_id, due_date, due_amount FROM month_dues where customer_id='1' where due_date>='2019-01-01' and due_date<='2019-10-18';
```

How to get pending due month and year using this table? 
Which means, find month and year not in this record.

Comment: First define exactly what YOU mean by ___pending due month and pending due year___

Comment: It will be good if you can show some of your table data and the expected output that you need so that other's can help you better.

Comment: My Guess is you would need to add something to the WHERE clause that uses the `due_date` somehow

Comment: pending due month and year means which month and year customer not paid.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to get customer data where the date is less than the current date today?

Comment: 'pending due month and year means which month and year customer not paid.' - how do you establish not paid from the published table?

Comment: suppose one month is not paid then this entry month(due_date) and Year(due_date) is not available in record.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are searching between the two dates

YOu can use this

```
 select * from month_dues 
 where due_date between '2012-03-11 00:00:00' and '2012-05-11 
 23:59:00' && customer_id='1'
 order by month_dues desc;
```

If you want to search the date(due_date) lower than today

```
SELECT * FROM month_dues WHERE due_date < CURDATE();
```

And you are refeering to the record that is not belong to the query you can find some `NOT IN` query
  Like

```
`SELECT * FROM month_dues NOT IN ( select * from month_dues 
 where due_date between '2012-03-11 00:00:00' and '2012-05-11 
 23:59:00' && customer_id='1'
 order by month_dues desc;
```

)`

Comment: this selects the paid dues. how to get pending due means which month is not available in record.

Comment: Your getting hard to get your work done because sometimes of your data structure, you can try also to put a column  status `Pending` or `Paid`

Comment: I edited my answer maybe that can explain you well use `NOT IN`

Comment: actually, suppose customer not paid then this record is not available in table

Answer (score 0):

So basically you need to validate your table against some kind of calendar, here is a simple solution that only works for the current year, maybe you can use it as a start or someone else could improve it

```
SELECT m.MONTH
FROM (SELECT 1 AS MONTH
      UNION SELECT 2 AS MONTH
      UNION SELECT 3 AS MONTH
      UNION SELECT 4 AS MONTH
      UNION SELECT 5 AS MONTH
      UNION SELECT 6 AS MONTH
      UNION SELECT 7 AS MONTH
      UNION SELECT 8 AS MONTH
      UNION SELECT 9 AS MONTH
      UNION SELECT 10 AS MONTH
      UNION SELECT 11 AS MONTH
      UNION SELECT 12 AS MONTH) as m
WHERE m.MONTH NOT IN (SELECT MONTH(due_date) 
                      FROM due_months 
                      WHERE customer_id = 1
                        AND YEAR(due_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())) 
AND m.MONTH < MONTH(CURDATE()) -- needs to be improved as well
```

Comment: but this want to find every year

Comment: @vijaykumar Yes I wrote that it was a simplified solution, something to build on and not a complete answer. I added a simple check for current year.